# Imprimir QR android

Tags: android, impresora, qr

Estoy intentando imprimir un código QR por una impresora térmica, la epson TM-T88V. String los imprimo sin problemas convirtiendo a array de bytes pero al pasarle un bitmap convertido a array de bytes me salen todos los caracteres raros y letras.

He leido que puede ser por que antes hay que imprimir un bytes[] para indicar que va a imprimir imagen. `byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE = {0x1B, 0x2A, 33, (byte) 255, 3};` pero este no funciona.

¿alguna idea? Tengo la imagen en bitmap y en `bytes[]`. Tambien intente convertir el bitmap a string e imprimirlo como imprimo texto pero el resultado es similar aunque solo letras sin caracteres raros.

por ejemplo para imprimor en negrita envio:  `printer.Print(context, setFontBold);` pero para imágenes no se.

Comment: Que marca de impresora tienes, revisa la página del fabricante ya que muchas veces el fabricante tiene un sitio para desarrolladores con ejemplos y SDKs listos para implementar.

Comment: Es una epson TM-T88V. Lo miraré gracias